# How to change the location of APPDATA?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

My C: is getting full regularly and now I don't have space. (It is less than 500Mb and system freezes or crashes often).  I have already moved all user documents to other harddrive.  I want to move `APPDATA` (which is around 1.5GB) files to D drive.  How to go about it.  I copied all of `appdata` (both local and roaming) to the other hard drive.  I need to change `%USERPROFILE%` from `c:\Users\{username}` to `D:\Users\{username}`.

I guess then I am done.  How to do it?  I couldn't find `userprofile` in the environment variables.

Comment: with that little space, i would consider moving the pagefile as well and make it static.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a safe way to move AppData\Local to a different drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/478095/what-is-a-safe-way-to-move-appdata-local-to-a-different-drive)

Answer (score 4):

Move your pictures and files to a second partition and use the Library feature of Windows 7:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/libraries

Also use [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) so see which other folders are very large and check those folders if you need them on C:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since this question has survived years and years without the duplicate flag being recognized, and since the only provided answer is to talk about the space used, and not about "how to change the location of APPDATA" ... in case someone else comes along who needs an answer to this, the answer is:

**Create a Symbolic Link or Directory Junction.**
This is different than a Shortcut, in that it serves as an actual alias that Windows treats like the directory itself.  So, if you're moving APPDATA, or the user directory from an SSD to a mechanical HDD for instance, you should consult these answers for how to create those links and move the files:

https://superuser.com/a/1250304/310715

https://superuser.com/a/478097/310715