# Running SSIS project take over c drive

Tags: hard-drive, visual-studio, ssis

I have a SSIS project that loads almost big data in OLEDB Source component and with some changes, Insert them in another destination.

when I run this project with SSDT, It takes all of free space in C drive and never runs properly because of lack of space. (I can not add any more space in C drive and I have tried using its capacity in the most efficient way)

I am using SSDT not SSDT for Visual Studio component and it doesn't allow me to change its install location. I don't know how but one of my colleagues changed the visual studio location to D drive but still when I run this project, It takes all of C drive's capacity.

Any ideas about how to change SSDT location to another drive? or how to change the project's temp loading files in any other place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is the increase of windows temp and appdata files. I managed to change these files location with these :

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2006/01/15/how-to-change-the-temporary-folder-if-you-run-out-of-space-while-burning-a-dvd-in-media-center/

&

[Can I move my AppData folder in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1250288/can-i-move-my-appdata-folder-in-windows-10)

and my problem is soled now...