# WindowsSearch not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-update, appdata

I decided to move AppData to D: and crated junction. I am not sure if it occurred because of this or because of Windows update shortly after, but ever since I am not able search for anything. I cannot search in folders nor in Windows Start menu. I tried reindexing. Strange things is that this issue doesn’t happen in other user accounts. It also doesn’t happen in Safe mood. With this issue also came problem that I cannot update my Windows for some reason. Neither in Safe mode. Can someone please help me? I don’t want to do the restore.

Also, Nvidia Gforce Experience stoped working.

Edit: Alrigth. Yesterday new larger update Finally appeared on my PC and it managed to update. The issue is gone because it moved appdata back to C: But damn! I need them at D: at all costs.

Here is the link for the original post I used to change location of AppData: [Can I move my AppData folder in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1250288/can-i-move-my-appdata-folder-in-windows-10)

Comment: Can you move the folder back to correct drive? And then rebuild the Search Index.

Comment: Well. I could do that. But I barely managed to move it for the first time. And the reason I moved it was because I desperately needed storage. So, I don’t have a slight idea how to manage to save enough space now. Given part of it was taken by that update.

Answer (score 0):

> I decided to move AppData to D: and created junction. I am not sure if
> it occurred because of this or because of Windows update shortly
> after, but ever since I am not able search for anything.

AppData is a major Windows folder and moving it has very most likely caused the issue (which will be exacerbated by Updates which assume AppData to be located with Windows).

A later comment was that the machine is desperately (your words) short of space.

AppData and like Windows folders (many of them) need to be located on Drive C: with Windows.

**Solution here:**

**(A)** Move AppData back to C: if you can make space.

**(B)** Otherwise. obtain a larger disk drive, back up your data, and then install Windows and all its folders on Drive C:

Comment: Which folders from AppData can be moved then?

Comment: Judging by other profiles there are only few MegaBytes worth of files which need to be on C: right?

Comment: My App Data folder is 16 GB.  If you have room, then move tack to C:  I clarified my answer

Comment: What I wanted to say was: If new user profile has only about 300MB of AppData, that should mean only 300MB is required by system and rest can be moved. Is that true?

Comment: New user profiles do not have much data which is why the number is so small.  What I have suggested is move the folders you put on D: back to C: to make Windows work again. Otherwise (if you do not have space) get a larger disk. The important thing is to have Windows components on Drive C: all together.

Comment: Well. The windows already updated and changed the location of the folders back. However I still need to move them to D: but I am not sure which ones can be moved. I already changed the location of the Roaming by changing it in the file options but now it is total mess.

Comment: Your comment about Updates is what I mentioned in my answer. The only thing practical to move is Documents (photos, videos, documents).  Even basic email (or cache) is better on Drive C:  I am pretty sure now a larger C: drive is called for.

Comment: Well this is Laptop. It is easier said than done. Also I think my SSD is good quality and that this will happen to every new drive if I won’t find a way to force Windows to save elsewhere. Not mentioning reinstalling all the definitely legit programs I have.

Comment: I have put bigger drives in laptops. If your basic drive is too small for your needs I am not sure what else to suggest. Your local computer store may be able to help.

Comment: It is 250GB. Windows just keeps filling it with shi*. I have only Microsoft Office installed on C: all documents, photos, other programs, etc. are on D:

Comment: Ok I made mistake it has only about 120GB. But still is it normal for Windows to use 90GB from those 120? Hibernation file is “only” 2GB as I am cleaning it regularly.

Comment: 120 GB is too small for a standard physical machine. People getting machines with this size of drive soon regret it.  I strongly suggest getting a larger drive for Windows and apps you need.