# Windows wrongly shows my AppData\Local folder to be 500GB more

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-11, appdata

I plan to move my `AppData` folder to `D:` drive because I have more space following this: [Can I move my AppData folder in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1250288/can-i-move-my-appdata-folder-in-windows-10). However when I try to copy the folder over before doing anything, Windows somehow shows this folder to be 558GB when it actually only takes about 47GB:

[image]

I did a scan with WinDirStat to confirm it and nothing looks out of order:

[image]

What is going on here?

Also in the SU article I linked above, there is no mention of copying the data. Do I need to copy it before running `mklink`? What happens to the existing data if I run `mklink`?

Update: compression is not enabled:

[image]

Update 2: using some manual "binary search", I found out the file that causes the problem:

[image]

It's not compressed as well but has the attribute "ready for archiving" checked:

[image]

Comment: it's 558 GB of data that uses 47.1 GB of disk space ... compression is being used

Comment: @jsotola none of my drives has compression enabled and even if they have that's a crazy compression ratio I don't think possible.

Comment: click the advanced button in the properties window

Comment: @jsotola it's not enabled, I added the screenshot.

Comment: @jsotola not only compressed files, sparse files and resident files also have smaller file size. Besides there may be hard links and symlinks

Comment: So I searched a bit about that file, looks like it somehow just "reserve" the space but does not actually occupy all of it. Unfortunately to Windows, that's the size and I couldn't copy it. [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/1186d89/file_name_userdataimg_taking_up_5120_gb/) [2](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/228778246/file-size-about-appdata-local-google-play-games-userdata-uspholt4-ds3-avd-userdata-img?hl=en)