How to set up two hard disks so that the one on which the system is installed does not get clogged with software?
I have 2 disks installed in my system: disk 1 (let's call it Z) with a capacity of 1TB and disk 2 (let's call it X) with a capacity of 256 GB (Z and X are like variables, not hard disk partitions).
Installing the system (Windows 11) and all the necessary software that weighs a lot on disk Z seems like a bad idea, because as the disk fills up with programs, the whole system will suffer, and the amount of programs that can fit on disk Z will not fit on disk X and the system will still suffer.
I want to set it up so that drive X (256gb) contains only the most necessary files for a Windows system so that it can just start up and show its interface, and drive Z (1TB) contains the rest of the files such as Program Files, AppData, Users, and other files that the system doesn't depend on very much to function and are located and filled on drive Z

What do you mean by "the whole system will suffer" ? Suffer from what? The time where programs have written to Windows or system32 directory are long gone. Splitting Windows and programs will only cause you trouble and a lot of headache. Just do yourself a favor and use a large system disk and put everything on it.

A common way to address the issue is to use the smaller for OS itself and Program Files, and move data (Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos and perhaps Downloads) to the larger drive. https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_move_your_desktop3d_objectsdownloadspicturesmusicand_video_folder_locations_in_windows_10.html . This has been addressed here and elsewhere many times. For AppData, see https://superuser.com/questions/1250288/can-i-move-my-appdata-folder-in-windows-10

This question is similar to: Can I move my AppData folder in Windows 10?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
